# How to connect to local SQL Server database?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, database-connection

I am creating a web application/website using ASP.net in visual studio 2010.  We have our basic website and I even created a SQL Server database which is in the `App_Data` folder of my web application folder.

I created tables and a few procedures, but I do not know how to have my web forms or their controller (C#) classes access the tables. Below is my rough setup to access it. I don't know what to set the string to equal. The database is in `webapplication1/App_Data/database.mdf`.

The file I want to access it is `webapplication/App_Code/DataConnect.cs`. What should the string equal. What do I need to do to test it?

```
{ 
SqlConnection _sqlConn = null;
string _connectionString = ?
 _sqlConn2 = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
 _sqlConn.Open();
}
```

Comment: http://connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Don't you need a database server to handle the information in the database file? Something that translates the queries? I don't know C# but I imagine your SqlConnection object needs to not be null. Rather, it should be an object that manages a valid database connection.

Answer (score 7):

You may use following connection string.

```
string _connectionString =@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

You can also add the connection string into web.config's connectionString section and later use it in code.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="CnStr" 
       connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

To retrieve connectionString from web.config

```
string _connectionString=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CnStr"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can manually write connection string into your code...**

```
string strcon = @"Data Source=SERVERNAME; Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME; Integrated Security=True";
```

OR

**Follow below steps to connect local SQL Server database...**

1. Go to View > Server Explorer/Database Explorer
2. Right click on Data Connections > Add Connection...
3. Select Server name, Choose authentication type, Select your created database.
4. Test your connection and then OK.
5. Right click on database > Properties and use connection string...

Check below link for more understanding....

- [Bind Gridview In ASP.NET](http://www.codescratcher.com/asp-net/bind-gridview-in-asp-net/)
- [Overview SQL Server Database](http://www.codescratcher.com/sql-server/overview-sql-server-database/)

Answer (score 0):

the connection string just like

```
string _connectionString =@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

if you have any connection string problem, please refer to http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks for the comment,  i have revised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below ways:

```
string _connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="+ 
        Server.MapPath("~/App_Data") 
        +@"\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

Or

```
string _connectionString =@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

Answer (score 0):

string _connectionString =@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"